# Chaining multiple callbacks to a single jquery promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have the following setup, and I'm curious if this is the correct way to do it.  It works correctly, but I'm just making sure that I'm doing it right, or if there is a better way to accomplish the same task.

```
//custom ajax wrapper
var pageLoadPromise = ajax({
    url: //call to webmethod
});

//this is the way I have been doing it
pageLoadPromise.done(cB1)
    .done(cB2)
    .done(cB3)
    .done(cB4)
    .done(function(){cB5(args);});
    //this function requires that cB1 has been completed

//I tried this and it worked as well
pageLoadPromise.done(cB1,cB2,cB3,cB4)
    .done(function(){cB5(agrs)});
```

Doing it both ways works, but like I said, am I wondering if it is this the correct way to accomplish this?

UPDATE:

I have made a small adjustment to my code, specifically for `cB1` and the callback to `cB5`

```
pageloadPromise.done(
    function(data){
        cB1(data).done(function(){
            cB5(args);
        });
     },cB2,cB3,cB4
 );

 function cB1(data){
     var cB1Promise = $.Deferred();
     ...

     cB1Promise.resolve();
     return cB1Promise;
 }
```

Comment: @Asad None of the callbacks return any data, but I am passing the `data` object to the first 4 callbaks.

Comment: @Asad: No. `.done` is not `.then`

Comment: @RobM: Why do you have 5 different callbacks that await the same data?

Comment: @Bergi the first 4 callbacks use different pieces of data that are returned from the web method. So on the page load, I am retrieving a lot of data that is required to initialize the page.  That data is then return in one `json`.  In that actual callback, I do something like this: `var cb1data= data.d.cb1data;`.  So they aren't all awaiting the same data.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Bergi, regardless of how you add the callbacks, they are all run in the order they are attached using `done`. So, `promise.done(cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4).done(cb5)` is the same as `promise.done(cb1).done(cb2).done(cb3).done(cb4).done(cb5)`.

To make sure `cb5` runs after `cb1` use:

```
promise.done( function(data) {cb1(data).done(cb5);}, cb2, cb3, cb4);
```

Remove `data` if you don't need it.

I played around with the scenarios in http://jsbin.com/moqiko/4/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. Regardless how they are attached, the callbacks are always executed in series. If one of them depends on results from anotherone, `then` should be used anyway instead of `done`.

Comment: @Bergi cb5 only requires that cb1 is complete before it executes, so it doesn't require any data, but it require that it has finished executing

Comment: @Bergi, you are correct. I was mistaken. These are all equivalent. `promise.done(cb1).done(cb2).done(cb3).done(cb4).done(cb5)`, and `promise.done(cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4, cb5),  `promise.done(cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4).done(cb5)`   I will update my answer.

Comment: none of these callbacks are returns a promise, so how could I do `cb1.done(...)` without creating a new promise object inside each function.  I tested this in my app, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> Doing it both ways works

Yes, they are pretty much equivalent (except for the `.done(function(){cB5});` which doesn't work).

> I am wondering if it is this the correct way to accomplish this?

Use the one you like better. This is more a design question than one of "correctness". However, both ways look quite odd in my eyes, and I've seen lots of promise code. I would recommend two different structures, depending on how your app is structured:

- You use the `pageLoadPromise` as a global cache for your initial data. It is then consumed in very different places, possibly at different times, for multiple different things (or maybe even repeatedly for the same thing). Then use `pageLoadPromise` repeatedly in each module:

  ```
  var pageLoadPromise = ajax({url: …}); // initialisation 

  pageLoadPromise.done(cB1); // somewhere

  …
  pageLoadPromise.done(cB2); // somewhere else

  …
  pageLoadPromise.done(cB3); // other place or time

  …
  ```
- You use the `pageLoadPromise` in one place only, and want to basically do one thing when it's loaded, except that it is structured in multiple subtasks; and each needs only a part of, not the whole structure. Then use a single callback only:

  ```
  ajax({url: …}).then(function(data) {
      cb1(data.d.cb1data);
      cb2(data.d.cb2data);
      cb3(data.d.cb3data);
      cb4(data.d.cb4data);
      cb5(data.d.cb5data, some_additional_data);
  });
  ```

> I have made a small adjustment to my code, specifically for `cB1` and the callback to `cB5`

You should not make `cb1` return a promise when it doesn't do anything asynchronous. Don't modify it. If you want to express explicitly that `cb5` needs to be executed with the result of `cb1`, then you should use `.then` for chaining:

```
var pageLoadPromise = ajax({url: …}); // initialisation 

var cB1promise = pageLoadPromise.then(cB1);

cB1promise.done(cb5); // does get called with the return value of cB1
```

or

```
ajax({url: …}).then(function(data) {
    var res1 = cb1(data.d.cb1data);
    …
    cb5(data.d.cb5data, some_additional_data, res1);
});
```

Comment: I like the first approach, but my app isn't structured that way. Also,I don't see what the difference is between using `.done` and `.then` in my case.

Comment: In your case, there is no difference, as your callbacks don't return anything, and nothing depends on their results.

Answer (score 0):

**Update.** Thanks to @Bergi who pointed out that jQuery's `done()` returns in fact the same promise. I've updated the answer based on that.

If `cB2`,`cB3`,`cB4` are not interconnected and all of them process the same data from the ajax call, then you can add them to the same promise (`pageloadPromise`).

With the above assumption in mind, your second version of code can be simplified without involving a new promise to be created in cB1(), and without having to go one extra indentation level:

```
pageloadPromise.then(cB1).done(cB5);
pageloadPromise.done(cB2, cB3, cB4);

function cB1(data){
    // ...     
    //data2 would be the argument value passed when resolving
    // your original cB1Promise
    return data2; 
}
```

What happens here is that the `.then()` call creates a new promise that gets resolved with whatever data `cB1` returns, allowing `cB5` to receive that data without creating an extra callback and without involving another promise (as we already have one in hand).

However if `cB1` needs another `ajax` then your original implementation of `cB1` would be more appropriate (the callback scheduling remains the same though).

And one final note, I didn't noticed any failure handlers, in case the ajax call fails.

Comment: My bad, I assumed the jQuery promises are behaving by the book and returning a new promise when. Thanks for pointing this, will update my answer